# How to install patches to ns2 that I installed using $ sudo apt install ns2?

Tags: command-line, patch, ns2

How to install patches to ns2 that I installed using `$ sudo apt install ns2`?

I am unable to find any ns2 directory anywhere. I know I can patch ns2 if I had installed it using ns allinone. But I want to know if it is possible if I installed it from terminal with the above command.

Comment: You need to ask the maintainer of the package to provide these. If those are security related they will be installed on all active Ubuntu. If not it is up to the maintainer. Ubuntu works with the lateste stable version at the moment of release of that Ubuntu. Upgrading to 21.10 might also include your patches.

Comment: The ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?resourcekey=0-eBw6mJFKhSVGultqaD2rDA ... One or more patch can be added to (the source) ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-EyPhoScBFDb7ul0VFk6FZQ ........ Examples ns2 https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ns2 .. and .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ns2

Comment: @knud thank you for the resources! But is it possible to patch the ns2, that is installed using terminal. I mean without using that tar file??

Comment: No. The installed package ns2 cannot be modified. Can be used for "examples.tcl with default protocols" only. ....... Adding an additional protocol / some modified code can be done only to the ns-2.xx source code. Alternatively you can install apps with a new protocol  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNcEpiMmRyNTVndFE?resourcekey=0-bTnJ3S5xWfaoGPAjJEkwzg&usp=sharing . .... Any questions? Then please specify your modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So from the above link,  can I install ns 2.35 with zrp and olsr protocols?  No need to add the patches manually?

Comment: OLSR + ZRP : `sudo apt install Downloads/umolsr+zrp-ns-2.33-ubuntu12_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRU9QRE04U05wc2c/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-tGLnq8WFQfjB0OzxuN-yGg ...... .... olsr+zrp_ns-2.35.txt  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJJm_nqRMWk-E80UKEtJ8kFfFEHi4qYv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing ... https://groups.google.com/g/ns-users ........... + https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/ns2/ ............... 3000 ns2 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?resourcekey=0-vrEMHtGTFP3yLoTQz_UAwA&usp=sharing

Comment: olsr+zrp-ns_2.35-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAG6LNgk5XWrDa8m1YUep762utIIAAWj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to install patches to ns2 that I installed using $ sudo apt
> install ns2?

Extra protocols = The ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?resourcekey=0-eBw6mJFKhSVGultqaD2rDA
One or more patch can be added to (the source) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-EyPhoScBFDb7ul0VFk6FZQ
Examples ns2 https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ns2
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ns2

The installed Ubuntu package `ns2` cannot be modified. Can be used for "examples.tcl with default protocols" only.
Adding an additional protocol / some modified code can be done only to the ns-2.xx source code. Alternatively you can install apps with a new protocol https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNcEpiMmRyNTVndFE?resourcekey=0-bTnJ3S5xWfaoGPAjJEkwzg&usp=sharing

> (Ref. apps:) can I install ns 2.35 with zrp and olsr protocols?

The app OLSR + ZRP : `sudo apt install Downloads/olsr+zrp-ns_2.35-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAG6LNgk5XWrDa8m1YUep762utIIAAWj/view?usp=sharing
Provides `/usr/local/bin/ns235-olsr-zrp`
Simulation : `$ ns235-olsr-zrp file.tcl`

ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing